# Copy the trigger file using Apache Camel once actual files copied

Tags: apache, apache-camel

I am newbie to Apache camel. My requirement is to copy all the actual files based on the regex patter.

Trigger file in the same directory should be copied to target folder once all the actual files are copied.

Please let me know how to do this.

Comment: Can you show what you tried?

Comment: Please have a look at Camel's file Component: http://camel.apache.org/file2.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the file2 component of Camel (here is the [doc](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html)).

Basically you can use it like this:

```
from("file://inobox?delete=false").to("bean:handleOrder");
```

But you can add options. For example to match patterns:

> include: Is used to include files, if filename matches the regex
> pattern.
>
> exclude: Is used to exclude files, if filename matches the
> regex pattern.